# Why are details not being returned for spring health indicator?

Tags: spring-boot

I am currently using spring boot 2.1.4 and jackson 2.9.8
When hitting the health endpoint the details are not displayed.

```
{
  status: "UP"
}
```

I have added the following property to my configuration.

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

When I look at the environment `management.endpoint.health.show-details` it is set.

When I monitor `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthWebEndpointResponseMapper.HealthWebEndpointResponseMapper(HealthStatusHttpMapper, ShowDetails, Set<String>)` it is showing that `ALWAYS` is in fact being used, and details is not being stripped out.

However, when it gets to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector` it doesn't add details, because the method `getDetails` has not been annotated in `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health` like it has with `getStatus` (being `@JsonWrapped`)

How do I get details to be serialized by Jackson, so they can be returned via the health endpoint?

EDIT: This appears to be getting caused by a custom ObjectMapper that is being injected into the spring environment at startup which sets both AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS and AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS to disabled. While this may of worked in spring 4, it no longer appears to work in spring 5.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything more than you have done already. There's no need for a `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation on `getDetails()`. `@JsonUnwrapped` only affects how a property is serialised to JSON not whether it's serialised. Can you share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) of the behaviour that you have described?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson While `@JsonWrapped` is not specifically required, it would seem as if a jackson annotation of some sort is required. POJOPropertiesCollector._addMethods, when adding a method checks the method for any jackson annotations, which it has none. I am going to try to upgrade my spring and jackson related libraries to the latest, and if it still happens I will attempt to create a new project with the same behavior that I can make available.

Comment: I don't believe any annotation is required, with Jackson as Spring Boot configures it at least. There are integration tests like [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/741d8735d28ad6d3c7708802e5620510287bbc49/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthEndpointWebIntegrationTests.java#L46-L51) that assert that the details are present. Perhaps you have customized Jackson and changed its serialization behaviour?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson You are correct, it does appear that a custom ObjectMapper is created which is disabling both AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS and AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS and it causing havoc.